# how to add right padding to 3 images whilst keeping all images in the same row

Tags: html, css

sorry about the newbie question but i am just starting in the world of web development. I am trying to get padding on the right of 3 images whilst keeping all images in the same row. I have tried putting each image in its own div however this puts a picture on a separate row. Thanks for the help

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can give a separate class to those 3 images and add the padding like this.

**HTML**

```
<img src="#1" class="mypad"/>
<img src="#2" class="mypad"/>
<img src="#3" class="mypad"/>
<img src="#4"/>
<img src="#5"/>
<img src="#6"/>
<img src="#7"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.mypad {
padding-right: 10px;
}
```

div takes 100% of the screen width, so you are getting each image in a new row.